# Is it possible to have constructor have different name as the class declared?

Tags: c++

I have a quick question while reading a source code. AFAIK, the name of a constructor should be identical to the class declared. But, the following code has a different name as a constructor. Anybody can tell me why this code works?

```
class directFieldMapper
:
    public FieldMapper
{
    const labelUList& directAddressing_;

    bool hasUnmapped_;

public:

    // Constructors

        //- Construct given addressing
        patchFieldSubset(const labelUList& directAddressing)
        :
            directAddressing_(directAddressing),
            hasUnmapped_(false)
        {
            if (directAddressing_.size() && min(directAddressing_) < 0)
            {
                hasUnmapped_ = true;
            }
        }

    //- Destructor
    virtual ~directFieldMapper()
    {}
}
```

Ok, I found that this class is not in the source code list in the Makefile. So, this class is never compiled.

Comment: patchFieldSubset is not a constructor for directFieldMapper.

Comment: That, or a typedef (maybe? not sure), or an evil macro.

Comment: "why this code works?" this code does not work, at least as shown here there will be a couple of compiler errors unrelated to the actual issue. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Could `patchFieldSubset` be a nested class inside `directFieldMapper`, and you just missed/accidentally omitted the relevant code? Indentation suggests that that could be possible.

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: "Is it possible to have constructor have different name as the class declared?" - No. Then it would not be a constructor. The same goes for destructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to have constructor have different name as the class declared?

No.

> AFAIK, the name of a constructor should be identical to the class declared.

Correct.

> But, the following code has a different name as a constructor.

The code is ill-formed according to C++ standard.

> Anybody can tell me why this code works?

If it works, then it is due to some language extension. You can consult the manual of your compiler about language extensions it provides, and how to enable / disable them.

Being ill-formed, all compilers are required to issue a diagnostic message, or else they are not compliant. Example output from the GNU compiler:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'patchFieldSubset' with no type [-fpermissive]

         patchFieldSubset(const labelUList& directAddressing)

                                                            ^

warning: non-static reference 'const labelUList& directFieldMapper::directAddressing_' in class without a constructor [-Wuninitialized]

     const labelUList& directAddressing_;

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: expected ';' after class definition

 }
  ^
```

Comment: I would mention that constructors cannot have different names because constructors have no names at all, accordingly with the standard.